# Test for empty cell Access DB VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm wondering on whether its possible to check if a specific cell in a record is empty before attempting to collect its value and crashing the program if it cant be assigned to a variable.

Something along the lines of `SELECT FirstNameColumn FROM tableNames WHERE LastNameColumn = "Smith"`, and to test if the `FirstNameColumn` has a value in it.

Im using VB.net, with the OleDB and an Access Database.

Comment: Select  FirstNameColumn From tableNames Where Not IsNull(FirstNameColum) And LastNameColumn = 'Smith';

Comment: @Mary please avoid answering questions via comments, but also (given that you recently made a performance related observation on an answer of mine, so I know you're interested in it performance in general) it'd be quite unusual (from a performance perspective especially) to query a db to see if a value was null, before issuing another query to retrieve the value, when a front end language can just run the retrieve query and handle the case where it's null quite easily

Comment: @CaiusJard Agreed. I have several pages on handling nulls with vb.net, not on the server but the OP didn't ask about handling locally; just how not to retrieve nulls.

Comment: Funny thing there; I read it differently. I can see how it would be parsed as "run a query to check if it's null then run a query to get it if it's not" but I could also see it as "how can I check if the reader Value for a getXXX is null first" - Really people should give up such low level database access and start using tableadapter/entity framework/dapper... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had some code that retrieved a record, and some of the values on the row might be null:

```
Public Sub ReadMyData(ByVal connectionString As String)
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT FirstNameColumn FROM tableNames WHERE LastNameColumn = 'Smith'"
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)

        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()


            If Not reader.IsDbNull(0) Then 
               Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0))
            End If

        End While

        reader.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

A DataReader has an IsDBNull method hat will tell you whether a cell on a row is null.

Really though, using a DataReader is really low level and quite hard work. There are a lot easier ways to use a database. The next step up might reasonably be a dataadapter and datatable, offering a similar function:

```
 Dim da as New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT FirstNameColumn FROM tableNames WHERE LastNameColumn = 'Smith'", connStr)  
 DataTable dt = new DataTable()  
 custDA.Fill(dt)  

 For Each ro as DataRow in dt.Rows
   If Not ro.IsNull("FirstNameColumn") Then
     Console.WriteLine(ro("FirstNameColumn"))
   End If
 Next ro
```

TableAdapters another level of abstraction, removes all the horrible dealing with string column names amongst other things:

```
 Dim ta as New PersonTableAdapter
 Dim dt as PersonDataTable = ta.GetData()
 For Each ro in dt
   If Not ro.IsFirstNameColumnNull() Then
     Console.WriteLine(ro.FirstNameColumn)
   End If
 Next ro
```

Entity Framework is probably equivalently high level, possibly higher:

```
Dim p as Person = context.Person.Where(Function(x) x.LastName = "Smith")
If p.FirstNameColumn Is Not Nothing Then
  Console.WriteLine(p.FirstNameColumn)
End If
```